# How to embed a kable inside a pre-existing HTML table? (or how to print kable table without the Table/body tags?)

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, knitr

I'm trying to embed the results of my R script into a bigger HTML table.
Something like that:

[image]

And the result is not quite what I expect, not knowing a lot about HTML, It seems the issues is that the table is define a as whole with the body and table tags.

Is there a way to ask knitr::kable to not print those and if so would it fix my issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this myself specifically with SharePoint. What works for me is maikng use of the IDE application 'Atom' to strip out the raw HMTL output of your Markdown output. That will also require you to use objects that output in HTML as well, which can take a little bit of trail and error.

Here's the link to Atom: 
[Atom IDE](https://atom.io/)

I would start by making sure you are getting your Kable output with a HMTL specifically.

Here's an example:

```
   df %>% kable("html", escape = F, row.names = FALSE)
```

Hope that helps!